# Using variables in a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string replacement regular expression:

```
var res = myString.match(/[.,]/g);
```

Now I want to store the pattern in a variable:

```
var usedSeparator =".,";
var regExp = new RegExp("["+usedSeparator+"]","g");
var res = myString.match(regExp);
```

But it doesn't work. How could I do such thing?

Comment: you need to escape '.' character, because it has a special meaning in regex. also you have to escape escaping '\' character used for escape dot, because it has a special meaning in js string :)

Comment: @JánStibila You don't have to escape `.` when it's inside a character class.

Comment: damn, you'r right :D

Comment: What doesn't work? What do you obtain? What do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you intended to use `split()`. Here, it works:

```js
myString = "I have seen it, but I forgot the name."
usedSeparator =".,";
regExp = new RegExp("["+usedSeparator+"]","g");
res = myString.split(regExp);
alert(res);
```